# Objective C inheritance: undefined symbols

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Why this code does not build?

I have following files:

**shape.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Shape : NSObject{}
    -(double)getArea;
    -(void)Log;
@end
```

**circle.h:**

```
#import "Shape.h"
@interface Circle : Shape {}
@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) double radius;
@end
```

**circle.m:**

```
#import "Circle.h"
#include <math.h>
@implementation Circle : Shape
-(void)setRadius:(double)radius{}
-(double)getArea{
    return self.radius * self.radius * M_PI;
}
-(void)Log{
    NSLog(@"The circle has an area of %f.", self.getArea)
}
@end
```

and **main.m:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Circle.h"
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Circle *c = [Circle alloc];
    c.radius = 10;
    [c Log];    
    return 0;
}
```

And I have build error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

[image: Build error]

What do I miss?

Comment: Where's your `shape.m` file?

Comment: I thought I may not to implement shape interface. Thank you.

Comment: All Objective-C classes need to be implemented.

Comment: And you can leave out the empty `{}` after `@interface`

Comment: I am voting up the question because there is nothing wrong with it - especially when you are coming from a different language where @interface mean a very different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Obj-C, `@interface` declares a class. All classes need to also have `@implementation`. In all C-like (C/C++/Obj-C) languages the header file is a promise - "what you see here is implemented somewhere". If the promise is not fulfilled (the implementation is missing), you will get compilation (linking) errors.

In this case, you are missing the implementation for the `Shape` class.

I can understand your confusion, especially when you are coming from a language where `interface` means an abstract set of methods. In Obj-C, similar things are called `@protocol`. Also, there are no abstract methods/classes in Obj-C. Every method that is declared must also be implemented (unless it's a protocol `@optional` method).

Answer (score 0):

You should either create a shape.m file with a default implementation for these methods, or make it a protocol, depending on your needs.